# Laravel 8 API email verification flow using Sanctum

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication, laravel-sanctum

I'm currently making an API for a mobile app but I think I'm a bit confused with how email verification and authentication is meant to work. I'm attempting to implement the following flow:

- User registers in the mobile app and it sends a request to the API
- Laravel creates the user and fires off an email
- User receives the email and clicks on the link
- Laravel verifies the user and redirects them to the mobile app via deep-link

However when the user clicks the email link a "route login not defined" error is rendered.
Which makes sense, because the user is not authenticated at the time. But am I getting this wrong?

Should I authenticate the user prior to sending the email? And will that work, given that we're using Sanctum rather than "regular" authentication?

Currently this is what I'm doing:

```php
// web.php

Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'verify'])
    ->middleware('signed') //note that I don't use the auth or auth:sanctum middlewares
    ->name('verification.verify');
```

```php
// EmailVerificationController.php

public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->id);

    if ($user->email_verified_at) {
        return '';
    }

    if ($user->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($user));
    }

    return redirect()->away('app://open'); // The deep link
}
```

Is there any security risk here? Should I at any point authenticate the user before or after they click the link?
I wanted to avoid rendering "web views" as much as possible.

Comment: Why don't you send a PIN to the user via email to be inserted in the app? This way you don't need web-views at all.

Comment: @WannyMiarelli That is a good idea actually. But I’d rather still try and understand what is going here exactly. Will keep the PIN idea in mind though!

Comment: I replicated your code and I'm able to complete the verification without any authentication check. If you are redirected to the login page (route login not defined) this means that somewhere this route is picked up by the auth filter. Hard to say where from your extracted code (maybe some global middleware?). In theory you should authenticate the use before validating the email, but i see no security issue in the opposite.

Comment: @WannyMiarelli this is my bad, I didn't make it clear that it is what happened *before* I wrote that code in the example and removed the auth middleware (if anyone has editing permissions, please fix that). What I did there was precisely bypass authentication and I wanted to know if it was ok. Turns out it is not completely ok, if not for the fact that I don't check the hash. I ended up going with the PIN route.

However, later on I will also want users to sign-in via a web app, so I'll have to work out how to send a regular verification email in that case.

Comment: I think that this is as simple as checking the source. If the user is coming from the mobile APP then you fire the PIN validation, otherwise the regular email is fired.

Comment: I believe so as well. Go ahead and create an answer of sorts, I want to get you some well deserved rep :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the best way is to implement two different paths based on the source of the user.

#### Regular email validation for users coming from a browser

The user will just follow the link delivered by email, you can do that with or without authentication (maybe with transparent cookie authentication). If the validation is fulfilled redirect them back to the home page.

#### Mobile users coming from the mobile application

I would send a PIN (with some kind of expire mechanism) via email and ask them to put it inside the APP to verify the account. This can even be protected with auth middleware using the JWT token with the verification API call.

I don't see any security issue with this last one.